# How to pass data into ejs templates?

Tags: html, templates, ejs, templating-engine

I have the following `html` snippet and I can see that it's using `ejs` and potentially some other templating engines.

```
<div class="swiper-slide slide7">
  <img src="~-IMAGE/img_1200x653_eBanking_03.7.png" class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-block d-sm-none" srcset="${require('-IMAGE/img_1200x653_eBanking_03.7.png')}" alt="">
  <div class="text-group-right">
    <h2 class="slide-title">${__('ebanking.dss.content.step.7.title')}</h2>
    <p class="slide-desc">${__('ebanking.dss.content.step.7.descriptions')}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not that familiar with `ejs` but am wondering if there's a way I can pass data, like the with template literals as seen in the example snippet/ image source, etc., as seen in the example, into snippets like these so it can save a lot of hassles.

Answer (score 0):

are you passing data from the backend, if so it is nodeJs? If it is, typically you have to set the value of the data you want to pass in the function from the backend, and then pass it through when rendering the page. if this is the case, I can explain more on how to do so

Comment: Actually, I am wondering if there’s a way to pass data on the frontend, like inside the template string but I’m not sure if that’s feasible

Comment: you could try doing a script. you could set the 'id' of the text element to whatever you like, and then put in the script var variable = document.getElementById('id'), and then you could try outputting that variable in whatever text element you like. not sure if that helps?